# Laravel 7: Calling data with a custom foreign key shows error

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

I have a department table. Here is a column name created_by. It stores the id from users table. I want to call the users name from created_by column's id. But it shows error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.department_id' in 'where clause'`

Department Model:

```
 public function user(){
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

User Model:

```
 public function department(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class, 'created_by');
}
```

Controller:

```
 public function index(){
    $departments = Department::where('deletion_status', 0)->orderBy('department', 'asc')->get();
    return view('admin.department_manage', compact('departments'));
}
```

Blade file:

```
   @foreach($departments as $row)
       <tr>
          <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
          <td>{{ $row->user->name }}</td>
       </tr>
   @endforeach
```

Can anyone please help me to find out the solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you specified laravel wrong relationships.  do this: for the user model `departments() { return $this-> hasMany(Department::class, 'created_by')}` Then for the department model: `user(){return $this->belongsTo(User::class, '  created_by', 'id')}.`  The call would be: `departments= Department::where('deletion_status', 0)->with('user')->get()` Each element in the departments collection will have information about a user.  , which can be obtained for example like this `department -> user->name`